# 'choco' command not recognized when run as administrator on Windows

Tags: windows, chocolatey

I installed Chocolatey as per the instructions on the website (https://chocolatey.org/install).

The 'choco' command works fine when I run it normally on cmd but returns the following error when run as administrator:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>choco install -y wget 7zip.commandline
'choco' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The install `choco install -y wget 7zip.commandline` fails if not run as administrator.

How do I fix 'not recognized' error in admin cmd?

Comment: Search this site for *not recognized as an internal or external command*, which will turn up literally thousands of existing posts regarding that same issue. In fact, you were shown many of them as potential duplicates when you posted; they're over there in the **Related** list --->>> Certainly at least one of them will tell you how to fix the problem. Doing at least a simple search here is part of making an effort to find a solution yourself before posting.

Comment: I've been going through such posts for the past 30 minutes. The command doesn't still work when I run cmd as administrator. I've checked the PATH. It's properly set. Yet the command only works when I open cmd normally (not as admin). Please can you point me to any question that mentions running cmd as admin?

Comment: In case you're using the newer Windows Terminal: you can't just open a new tab.  You need to restart the entire Windows Terminal application to recognize env var updates.

Answer (score 64):

1. First, ensure that you are using an administrative shell of command prompt(https://www.howtogeek.com/194041/how-to-open-the-command-prompt-as-administrator-in-windows-8.1/).
2. Copy the below text into the command prompt.

   ```
   @"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
   ```
3. Then press enter key from the keyboard. After few seconds you get complete info about current installation.
4. If you don't see any errors. Type `choco` or `choco -?` now.

[Reference](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/Installation#installing-chocolatey)

Comment: Does not work for me. How does this differ from the normal choco installation?

Comment: Thank youuuu duuude

Comment: I got `Access Denied`. Anyways to overcome that? Have already run cmd as Administrator.

Comment: That howtogeek link now only shows a 404 error.

Answer (score 30):

The `choco` `environment variable` has been altered. I ran into a similar problem when I tried setting `env variable` for `Java SDK`, but I was quick to recognize it when I ran the `commands` presented to me in the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openjdk/11/html/openjdk_11_for_windows_getting_started_guide/getting_started_with_openjdk_for_windows#installing_openjdk_msi_installer) which completely overwrites my env `Path variable`.

If you are sure you've choco installed. Check your `System variables` and look for `Path variable` if it has some values like `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco.exe;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin` if not `add` it.

And you can save you time by installing it. Installing via cmd line

Powershell:

Copy and Paste the code below to your PowerShell

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

OR Window CMD.exe:

```
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
```

After installation: run `choco` you see the version of chocolatey installed. Mine

```
Chocolatey v0.10.14
Please run 'choco -?' or 'choco <command> -?' for help menu.
```

hopefully this help [read more](https://chocolatey.org/install#installing-chocolatey)

Comment: In Windows 11 I open powershell as admin and run your code. It  works. Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

First Open the Command prompt as administrator and then run -

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin
```

And then restart the Command prompt, now choco is successfully installed

Comment: Unfortunately also this does not work for me, although `SET PATH` could be the way to go

Answer (score 4):

Open command prompt in administrator mode and run this command:

```
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command " [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
```

Comment: I suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 2):

Just correcting what @Krishnarjun Banoth has given in the answer:

```
powershell -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"
```

You don't have to add the PATH variable because choco will automatically add itself to PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the Path entry from 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin' to 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey' and rebooting Windows did the trick for me.

Comment: You can also run `refreshenv` instead of rebooting.

Answer (score 1):

**To install chocolatey yarn:**

First of all

Download the installer
This will give you a .msi file that when run will walk you through installing Yarn on Windows.

If you use the installer you will first need to install Node.js.

[https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#windows-stable](https://Download%20installer)

And, then go for choco install

Powershell:

Copy and Paste the code below to your PowerShell

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

OR Window CMD.exe:

```
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
```

After installation: run choco you see the version of chocolatey installed.

**choco -v**

After that just do one more thing

in PowerShell or cmd just copy-paste the following command to install chocolatey yarn in your system

choco install yarn

Here your yarn has been installed, check your yarn version using the following command.

**yarn -v**

That's it!! :)

This will definitely work :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the installation to work using `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\choco.exe install -y wget 7zip.commandline`. I'm still wondering why the `choco` command isn't working when cmd is run as administrator. I would appreciate any help. Cheers!

Comment: This should be another question or comment @Moderator

Answer (score 0):

Hi for installing choco on your windows system, follow these steps:

- First open cmd as admistrator.
- copy this command in the cmd (as administrator):

```sh
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
-NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object
System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"
&& SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
```

This will download the required dependency for choco and install it in your windows system.

For cross check run the choco command, for ex:

```
choco install -y nodejs.install python2 jdk8
```

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted, but I also found that you had to use cmd. Powershell didn't work for me, but running the same thing in cmd it worked immediately.